# Pig error 1070 when doing UDF

Tags: java, hadoop, user-defined-functions, apache-pig

I am trying to load up my own UDF in pig. I have made it into a jar using eclipse's export function. I am trying to run it locally so I can make sure it works before I put the jar on HDFS. When running it locally, I get the following error:

`ERROR 1070: Could not resolve myudfs.MONTH using imports: [, org.apache.pig.builtin., org.apache.pig.impl.builtin.]`

### Script

```
REGISTER myudfs.jar; 
--DEFINE MONTH myudfs.MONTH;

A = load 'access_log_Jul95' using PigStorage(' ') as (ip:chararray, dash1:chararray, dash2:chararray, date:chararray, getRequset:chararray, status:int, port:int);
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.MONTH(date);
DUMP B;
```

### Function

```
package myudfs;
import java.io.IOException;
import org.apache.pig.EvalFunc;
import org.apache.pig.data.Tuple;
import org.apache.pig.impl.util.WrappedIOException;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class HOUR extends EvalFunc<String>
{
    public String exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        if (input == null || input.size() == 0)
            return null;
        try{
            String str = (String)input.get(0);
            return str.substring(1, 3);
        }catch(Exception e){
            throw WrappedIOException.wrap("Caught exception processing input row ", e);
        }
    }
}
```

### Working Directory

```
1.pig  2.pig  bin  myudfs.jar  
pig.jar  pig-withouthadoop.jar  src/
```

### Running command

`pig -x local 2.pig`

### Structure of jar

```
 0  Thu May 02 12:16:26 MDT 2013 META-INF/
68  Thu May 02 12:16:26 MDT 2013 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
 0  Thu May 02 12:05:50 MDT 2013 myudfs/
573 Thu May 02 12:15:10 MDT 2013 myudfs/HOUR.java
```

I am really close to start chucking monitors, so I am just looking for some help and direction. Let me know what could be wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your UDF class name is called `HOUR`

So shouldn't your pig latin be this?

```
B = FOREACH A GENERATE myudfs.HOUR(date);
```

Comment: ... Just shows how important it is to take a sanity break, and how important it is not to over assume. Thanks so much man, you sure are right.